# Can anybody suggest an open source java project with requirement specification document and junit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, open-source, junit, requirements

I am looking for an open source java project which has requirement specification documents (use case or user story etc.) and have junit tests. I have found many projects with just junit tests. But I could not find any project with both requirement documents and junit tests.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Look into [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) or [FITnesse](http://fitnesse.org/).

They are acceptance testing frameworks, tools that allow to do just what you're looking for: turn user stories into actual tests that you can add to your build and run dinamycally against production code.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. But i'm not looking for acceptance testing framework. I'm searching for an open source java project which has some requirements docs and has some junit tests for that project. Actually I'll use that project as a case study for academic purpose. 
I have found one such open source project which has some use cases and junit tests - http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/iTrust/wiki/doku.php . I need another project to complete my case studies.

Comment: Ah I see, I don't know of any, sorry :)